# How to give meaningful classnames in styled-jss?

Tags: jss

I'm using `styled-jss` in my app. During development it compiles my components to ugly classnames and I see this in my Web Inspector

```
<div class="div-2-0-1-1">
    <div class="div-3-0-1-2">
        <div class="div-4-0-1-4">
            <div class="div-5-0-1-5"></div>
            <div class="div-6-0-1-6"><textarea class="textarea-7-0-1-7"></textarea></div>
            <div class="">
                <div class=""><input class="input-8-0-1-8"><input class="input-9-0-1-9"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd rather want to see component names in my classnames. I've set `mode: 'development'` in my `webpack.config.js` but this didn't help. Is there something I can do about it?

Answer (score 0):

Automated way to do that would require to build a babel plugin that would take the variable/identifier name and pass it to the styled function and later use it as part of the className.  This doesn't exist yet and we are working on a new version here if you want to follow https://github.com/cssinjs/jss/pull/1094